# bachfile to run taskkil for specific task in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taskkill

i want to make a batch file to run cmd and using *takkill* command to stop specific task in windows.
i used this code within a file named *batch.com* to stop *explorer*:

```
start "runas /user:administrator" cmd /k "taskkill /im explorer.exe /f"
```

but when i execute the batch file a black windows appeare and then shows this error message in a dialogue box.

```
c:\user\jack\desktop\batch.com
The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction.
CS:0000 IP:0077 OP:f0 37 05 0e 02 choos 'close' to terminate the application.
```

it has two button *close* and *Ignore* and bothe close the black window without doing anything.

when i tried the command

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
```

directly in cmd it works properly.

Comment: why the .com extension? batch files should be .bat

Comment: `.com` are supposed to be _binary_ executables (it's the "old form" of `.exe`). Batchfiles have either `.bat` or `.cmd`.

Comment: thanks @Stephan. That was the problem...when i used .bat the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rostok and @Stephan the problem is the extension. File extension should be .bat